# How to run two activities on different days in same ADF pipeline on different days?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF pipline which has to be run daily. Activity 1 and 2  should trigger every day. But there is one condition. On every Sunday activity 3 has to be run. On the other 6 days, activity 4 has to be run.

Is it possible to do it in ADF? 
Or do I have to create two separate pipelines one to run on size days and another one to run on Sundays?

Can somebody help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you add a [If Condition activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity) before active 3 and 4 :

[image]

Using bellow expression to filter the Sunday and other day of week in the If Condition expression:

```
@equals(dayOfWeek(utcnow()),'0')
```

Get the day of week from current UTC time, then compare to the return integer(Sunday is 0).

Add the Copy active 3 to Ture active, add Copy active to False active.

All the copy actives will run in the rule:

1. Monday--Saturday: Copy active 1,2,3 will be triggered.
2. Sunday: Copy active 1,2,4 will be triggered.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I try to use `@equals(dayOfWeek(utcnow()), '6')` to trigger my pipeline on every saturday,but failed.Because `dayOfWeek(utcnow())` return value is int,I changed it `@equals(dayOfWeek(utcnow()), 6)` and it work.

List of `dayOfWeek()` return value

- Sunday:   0
- Monday:   1
- Tuesday:  2
- Wednesday:    3
- Thursday: 4
- Friday:   5
- Saturday: 6

Comment: You are right. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#dayOfWeek